# jQuery for removing rows of a table

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript for checking if the table has the same number of rows as that in the select option, if not then delete those rows, so I wrote the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#noOfSegments").change(function() {
        var counter = $("#noOfSegments").val();

        for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            var row = $("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td></tr>");

            $("#segmentTable").append(row);
        }

        if (segmentTable.rows.length > counter) {
            var rowLen = segmentTable.rows.length;
            var delIndex = 1;

            for (i = 0; i <= rowLen; i++) {
                if (i > counter) {
                    segmentTable.deleteRow(i - delIndex);
                    delIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

<select id="noOfSegments">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

and `#segmentTable` is my table id
but I want some jQuery code for doing same, can you help me write it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your markup ?

Comment: You've tagged your question with `jQuery` tag, but your question shows you're not using it. 1. If you're not using it, please remove this tag. 2. Whatever you're trying to do, it'll probably be a lot easier with jQuery.

Comment: Why you want to change it to `jQuery`, when you get it in pure `JS`?

Comment: you want the above function to be written in jQuery? Why fixing what is not broken?

Answer (score 0):

-Update-

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C7Ygh/

js:

```
$("#noOfSegments").change(function(){
    var count = $("#noOfSegments").val();
    var rowcount = $("#segmentTable tr").length;
    while (rowcount > count) {
    $("#segmentTable tr:last-child").remove();
    rowcount = $("#segmentTable tr").length;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand where is the chance for extra rows as you are appending rows in for loop based on `select` value.

But based on the counter if you want to remove extra elements, check how many are added extra and remove them.

```
  var counter = $('#noOfSegments').val(), 
      Rows = $("#segmentTable > tr");
  if(Rows.length > counter){
      Rows.slice(counter - Rows.length).each(function(){
          $(this).remove();
      });
  }
```